# Алгоритмы в графах. Найти кратчайшие пути от всех точек графа до всех других

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

Есть взвешенный граф и дан список смежности весов в файле.

- 2;11
- 3;1 4;6 1;11
- 2;1 4;2
- 3;2 2;6

Где 2;11 - означает, что 1 вершина соединена со 2 вершиной ребром весом 11. 3;1 - означает, что 2 вершина соединена с 3 вершиной ребром весом 1 и т.д.
Структура хранения этого списка - односвязные списки.

```
    struct data{
    int node;
    int weight;
};
       //...........
        data x{};
        List<data> *a;
        a = new List<data> [n];
 
        cout << "Чтение матрицы весов ребер:\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            for (int i = 0; i < countInRow[j]; i++) {
                fscanf(f1, "%d;%d", &x.node,&x.weight);
                a[j].push_back(x);
            }
        }
        cout << "Матрица кратчайших путей:" << endl;
        Dijkstra(a,n,0);
```

Нужно найти матрицу кратчайших путей. Пробовал алгоритмы Флойда — Уоршелла и Дейкстры, но ничего не получилось. Везде они даны для матрицы весов. Пробовал переделать их под свою структуру хранения, начались ошибки с памятью.

upd: Сделал функцию, которая возращает вес ребра и переделал алгоритм Флойда - Уоршелла под списки. Теперь я можно сказать восстановил матрицу весов, но кратчайшие пути не считает.

```
int foo(List<data> *a,int row,int col){
if (row == col) return 0;
int size = a[row-1].GetSize();
for (int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    if (a[row - 1][i].node == col) {
        return a[row - 1][i].weight;
    }
}
return 10000;
```

}

```
void Floyd_Warshall(List<data> *a, int numberOfVert) {
int **matrix=new int*[numberOfVert];
for (int i=0;i<numberOfVert;i++)
    matrix[i] = new int [numberOfVert]{};
for (int k = 0; k < numberOfVert; k++) { //Пробегаемся по всем вершинам и ищем более короткий путь через вершину k
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVert; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfVert; j++) {
            if (i!=j) {
              matrix[i][j] = std::min(foo(a,i+1,j+1), foo(a,i+1,k+1) +
                                                      foo(a,k+1,j+1));
            } //Новое значение ребра равно минимальному между старым ребром и суммой ребер
        }
    }
}
//Печать матрицы кратчайших путей
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVert; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfVert; ++j) {
        cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

}

Comment: Ну вы же сами сказали — алгоритм Флойда-Уоршелла. Зачем вы строите списки? Читайте сразу в матрицу, и вперед...

Comment: @Harry Задание такое, что граф представляется двумя способами (матрицей
 весов и списками смежности). Для каждого представления
требуется написать отдельную программу решения задачи, используя
алгоритм, наиболее подходящий для используемой структуры хранения. Для матрицы весов я сделал, остались списки

Answer (score 0):

Всё изменение, которое вам нужно сделать для использования в работающем алгоритме Флойда-Уоршелла - написать функцию, которая будет возвращать вес ребра, если такое присутствует в списке, или большое число, если ребра нет.

И использовать её там, где вы брали веса из матрицы

Comment: Сделал, как вы сказали, теперь считает первую строку матрицы, затем выдает ошибку. Изменил описание, прикрепил код.

Comment: Ваш код запутан. Односвязные списки декларировались, по факту их нет, ну да ладно, без них проще. Почему используется `*a`? Что такое делается с matrix?

Comment: Упс, забыл как создается двумерный динамический массив, исправил. Теперь считает просто матрицу весов, но не кратчайших путей. *a - это ссылка на массив односвязных списков.

Comment: Если вам действительно нужны cами пути, то заведите ещё одну матрицу предков, и обновляйте её при срабатывании выбора минимума (свой if вместо std::min)

Comment: Вообщем, сделал все проще, написал функцию которая переделывает списки в матрицу весов и воспользовался алгоритмом Флойда, но все равно спасибо вам.